# OpenCV-Python Error (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, opencv, path

Consider the following code:

```
import cv2

# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades +
                                       'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

while True:
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(frame)
    for face in faces:
        # extract
        x, y, width, height = face
        x2 = x + width
        y2 = y + height
        # draw a rectangle over the pixels
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

        # show the image
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # keep the window open until we press a key
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # close the window
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

There is a problem that when I run this line of code

```
faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(frame)
```

I always get the same error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c2l3r8zm\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

[As you can see, I have the two files in the same folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpnro.png)

I've tried all the solutions that I've seen, like giving the whole path for the classifier, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files being in the same folder means nothing.

Relative paths are resolved relative to the **current working directory**, not the directory the script resides in.

Further, your code uses `cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'` which is likely an absolute path.

You should check if a file exists at that location.

Then... **always** error-check.

You are missing several error checks.

1. Right after `classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier...` you must check if that succeeded:

```py
assert not classifier.empty()
```

**That is likely the issue here. The violated assertion (error message) checked for this condition.**

2. Right after `vid = cv2.VideoCapture...` you must check if that succeeded:

```py
assert vid.isOpened()
```

3. After reading each frame (`ret, frame = vid.read()`), you must check if that succeeded:

```py
if not ret: break
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file is not available in the path you specified. Try printing the path to check. Also check if `classifier.empty()` returns `true` to know if the file is empty.